# Titles for /questions pages are misleading

Tags: feature-request, questions, voting, sorting, hot-questions

The title of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?page=152&sort=votes (last page of questions sorted by votes; the lowest voted questions) is "Highest Voted Questions". This is obviously not true. It should be "Questions (sorted by votes)" or something similar.

Other examples:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?page=152&sort=hot (the least hot questions [coldest questions?]) is "Hottest Questions"
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?page=152&sort=active is "Recently Active Questions"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really do not see the need to change the page title.

To most people (or to me at least), at page N of any particular list of sorted pages, "Highest XXX" implies sorting by XXX in ascending order, even though at the last page you see the lowest.

The fact that you navigate to the last page of "Recently Active Questions" also implies that you know you have clicked to sort by "Activeness" before going to the last page.

If your proposal is to have "Least Active Questions" for the last page, then how about 2nd last? Or rather from page 2 onwards because only page 1 displays the top.

BTW, "Least Active" is not the same as the inverse of "Recently Most Active".

Comment: I don't think it should be "Least Active", just "Questions (sorted by activeness)" or something similar.

Comment: I see, ok that sounds fair and fine to me :) And it should be "Sorted by recent activeness" or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 'Vote Ordered Questions', that way the word 'Vote' appears first for those of us who use a lot of tabs.